# Consider the two point space $X = \{a, b\}$ equipped with the topology $T = \{\emptyset, X, \{a\}\}$. Prove that $X$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve this problem and I am unsure of where to start. Would it be enough to just show that every pair of points, i.e. $a,b$, can be joined by a path in $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: [0,1] \to X$ given by $f(x)=a$ if $0\le x < 1$ and $f(1)=b$.

Then $f^{-1}[\{a\}]= [0,1)$, which is open in $[0,1]$, and so are $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ and $f^{-1}[X]=[0,1]$. So the inverse images of all open subsets of $X$ is open, so $f$ is continuous and thus a path from $a$ to $b$, showing that $X$ is path-connected.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that there exists a continuous map $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow X$ with $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$.

Comment: Assume X is a path connected space with a nonempty open and closed subset a such
that $a\neq X$  Let γ : [0, 1] → X be a path on X such that γ(0) = x and γ(1) = y where
x ∈ X \ a and y ∈ a. Because of the continuity of γ, $γ^{-1}$(a) is an open and closed subset of [0, 1]. But because [0, 1] is a connected space, the only open and closed sets are either the empty set or [0, 1], so $γ^{-1}$(a) must be all of [0, 1]. Therefore a = X, i.e., X is a connected space.

Comment: Would the above solution be correct then?

Comment: @DataD96 You need to show that $X$ is path connected with that topology. You can't begin the proof assuming what you must to show. Besides, to conclude that $X$ is connected, note that the clopen sets in that topology are only $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: @DataD96, you just need to prove existence, so construct a continuous function $f$ that satisfies the conditions, and you're done. You may see Godel's answer for an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\{a,b\}$ such that $f(x)=a$ iff $x\in[0,\epsilon)$ for some $0<\epsilon<1$.

Comment: okay, how about this solution then. Given x, y ∈ X and a, b ∈ R, a < b. Now X is a pathwise connected space implies there exists a continuous function say $f_{1}$ : [0, 1] → X such that $f_{1}$(0) = x and $f_{1}$(1) = y. Now let $f_{2}$(x) = x−a/b−a, x ∈ [a, b]. Now $f_{2}$ is a continuous function such that $f_{2}$(a) = 0 and f2(b) = 1. Hence g : $f_{1}$ ◦ $f_{2}$ : [a, b] → X is a continuous function such that g(a) = $f_{1}$($f_{2}$(a)) = $f_{1}$(0) = x and g(b) = $f_{1}$($f_{2}$(b)) = $f_{1}$(1) = y.

Comment: @DataD96 $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is not a well-defined point of $\{a,b\}=X$.....